# Chaining IQueryable expression trees

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, expression-trees, iqueryable

I want to be able to add ordering to my queries dynamically:

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<MyEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<MyEntity>>> order1 = e => e.OrderBy(x => x.Weight);
Expression<Func<IQueryable<MyEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<MyEntity>>> order2 = e => e.OrderByDescending(x => x.Weight).ThenBy(x => x.Price);
Expression<Func<IQueryable<MyEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<MyEntity>>> order3 = e => e.OrderBy(x => x.Category).ThenBy(x => x.Price);

IQueryable<MyEntity> query = any EF query;

var transformedQuery = query.Transform(order1/order2/order3);
```

How do I implement `Transform()` ?

```
public static IQueryable<T> Transform<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>> orderExpr)
{
   // ??????????????????
}
```

My problem is that I don't want to have 2 overloads for ascending/descending ordering. I need to apply whatever `OrderBy()/OrderByDescending()` expression or their combination is passed.

Comment: Can you not add the first order by in AddOrder too?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I need a generic method that will perform other transformations after adding ordering to a query.

Comment: What's the problem with the original OrderBy/ThenBy? As @hdv said you don't need anything else (if I don't miss anything...)

Comment: The example doesn't make sense.Let's take the first 2 examples.
The first orders by Weight and the second  orders by Weight Descending!!! What is it supposed to do in the end???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one case where you *don't* need an expression tree. Or even a helper method.

```
Func<IQueryable<MyEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<MyEntity>> order = e => e.OrderBy(x => x.Weight);
IQueryable<MyEntity> query = any EF query;

var transformedQuery = order(query);
```

This works because when `order` is passed in a query, it can itself call the appropriate `Queryable.OrderBy` overload that takes an expression tree.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I need an ordering param as an expression because the transformed query will be passed to EF provider.

Comment: @UserControl `order` will pass in `x => x.Weight` as an expression tree. This is enough to allow EF to translate it to SQL. When you write `context.MyEntities.OrderBy(e => e.MyProperty)` directly, this is a direct call to `Queryable.OrderBy` the same way.